# How to apply a function to each row of a "double" object (a data matrix)

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply

I can't work out how to apply the HWf function from the HardyWeinberg package to a "double" object, or data matrix. The function takes only one row with three columns, but I'd like to apply it to each row in turn of a three columned vector. I'd like the output to be a vector or column of HWf results (usually each is a decimal like 0.25). Here's how far I've got so far, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
library(HardyWeinberg)
a <- data.frame(AA=c(1,1,2,1), AB=c(2,3,5,4), BB=c(5,6,8,7))
b <- data.matrix(a)
c <- lapply(b, function(x) HWf(x))
```

Comment: try: `c <- apply(b, 1, HWf)`

Comment: Perfect, that worked great, thanks!